# { "message": "Cannot access 'user' before initialization" }

Tags: node.js, database

so the problem when i try to test the post request in the postman application I get this kind of error "{
"message": "Cannot access 'user' before initialization"
}" I don't know the source of this error exactly
this is all my code :

```
userRouter.js file:
import express from "express";
import data from "../data.js";
import expressAsyncHandler from "express-async-handler";
import user from "../models/userModel.js";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { generateToken } from "../utils.js";


const userRouter = express.Router();

userRouter.get('/seed', expressAsyncHandler(async(req, res) => {
    //await user.remove({});
    const createdUsers = await user.insertMany(data.users);
    res.send({createdUsers});

}));

userRouter.post('/signin', expressAsyncHandler(async(req, res)=> {
    const user = await user.findOne({email: req.body.email});

    if(user) {
        if(bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password)) {
            res.send({
                _id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                email: user.email,
                isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
                token: generateToken(user)
            });
            return;
        }
    }
    res.status(401).send({message: "User email or password invalid! "})
}))
export default userRouter;




util.js file: 

import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

export const generateToken = (user) => {
    return jwt.sign(
        {_id: user._id, 
            name: user.name, 
            email: user.email, 
            isAdmin: user.isAdmin 
        }, process.env.JWT_SECRET,
        {expiresIn: "30d"}
        )};
.env file:
JWT_SECRET =somethingsecret;
```

Comment: You should include code from userModel file as well.

Comment: Maybe the path to userModel is not good. Are you doing the proper import?

Comment: it's good.the path is imported correctly my friend.

Comment: but the only thing i didn't i guess is to add .env to gitignore.so I don't had this option to added it in gitignore so I write it in the end of gitignore file.

Comment: Can you try renaming const user this variable to userData or userRecord, I mean something else and then test?

Comment: try to write output in console of await user.findOne({email: req.body.email}) in Post requirest.

console.log(await user.findOne({email: req.body.email})) and see log returns you user from MongoDB?

Comment: nothing display that's backend database my friend

Comment: The problem might be totally unrelated to the code that you posted. Are you using an ORM like typeorm? In typeorm you need to define your entities in the ormconfig.js file. So it could be that your code is simply unaware of user because some kind of config is missing.

Comment: no my friend i don't work with ORM.